# Button to be able to input current time when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm fairly new to scripting so please be patient and gentle with me. I have the following code which fetches the time and allows me to pass it to a database (MySQL) when another button is pressed.

```html
<form action="includes/data_input.inc.php" method="POST">

    <!--  button - Start Timer -->
    <timer>
 <input id="starttime_button" name = "starttime_button" type="button" value="Start Timer"
               onclick="document.getElementById('starttime').value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'})" />
 <input type="time" id="starttime" name="starttime" value="" />
    </timer>
```

This works ok in Firefox, but not in Google Chrome. Is there a generic code that will let me do this, please?

I have tried many things including this, but it's not quite working ...

```html
<form action="includes/data_input.inc.php" method="POST">

    <!--  button - Start Timer -->
    <timer>
 <input id="starttime_button" name = "starttime_button" type="button" value="Start Timer"
               onclick="getElementById('starttime').Date('i:s')" />
        <p type="time" id="starttime" name="starttime" value="" ></p>
    </timer>
```

In both cases, the main form continues and is terminated with `</form>`

Thanks in advance.

Brian.

Comment: Look into Chrome console for possible error. Please remove "java" tag from your question, since this is not a java related question.

Comment: Get us a JSFiddle please. :)

Comment: @ Armaiti - This is all new to me - I dont know what I would be looking for in the Chrome console. How do I get to it?. Also, I dont even know why it isnt a java question. Is java not for web pages? Totally lost here and need my hand holding and gently guiding please.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Please do not ask for Fiddles (or any other 3rd party links) when code can be inserted into snippets right here. 3rd party links can become broken over time, making the question unreadable. Not to mention that it is much simpler to see everything here than part here and part somewhere else.

Comment: Anyone know why my question has a -1 value? - have I done something wrong with the quesion and made it not valid? I will never understand these ratings. I just want to ask and learn.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cant believe the reason this didnt work. My original code was ok...

```html
<form action="includes/data_input.inc.php" method="POST">

    <!--  button - Start Timer -->
    <timer>
 <input id="starttime_button" name = "starttime_button" type="button" value="Start Timer"
               onclick="document.getElementById('starttime').value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'})" />
 <input type="time" id="starttime" name="starttime" value="" />
    </timer>
```

Its just that the size if the box that displayed the time was too small. Changing the CSS code to expand the display box and it all worked as I would have expected it to in the first place. I still cant understand why, but that is secondary and food for thought to see why this is an issue at a later date.

Thank you to all of the contributors to this thread. I really do appreciate your time and effort on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your script into attributes, it is much better to put it either in a separate JavaScript file, or inside of script tags.  To fix up what you have so far:

```html
    <form action="includes/data_input.inc.php" method="POST">
        <!--  button - Start Timer -->
     <timer>
         <input id="starttime_button" name = "starttime_button" type="button" value="Start Timer" onclick="setStartTime()" />
         <input type="text" id="starttime" name="starttime" value="" />
     </timer>
    </form>

    <script>
        function setStartTime(){
            document.getElementById('starttime').value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'});
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Now, you have working code, but with no explanation as to what the problem was or what the solution is.

Comment: Thanks h01001000. Trouble here is the 1/2 working version allows you to see when the button was pressed. This code doesnt do that - unless I have swapped it in wrongly. Should the script be in the header?

Comment: Often, script tags are within the body tags as the very last items before the closing '</body>'.  If you want the date to be hidden, you could use the type 'hidden' as Scott Marcus suggests.  Otherwise you may want to try changing the input 'starttime' to a type of 'date', but then you could need to change how the date object is handled in the script.

Comment: Retried this and it does show the time the button was pressed - sorry for bad info last post. Unfortunately it breaks the next page that uploads the data to the database. I think this might be a failing of my code, but every input is not recognised - I get a "Undefined Index" errors.

Comment: Does this solution get the data to your database?  If so please mark the question as answered.  If the data is stored in the database but the problem lies with the return on the following page, the issue may be the format you are saving the date in versus what the next page is expecting.  However, this should be handled in a separate question.

Comment: Sorry h01001000. As stated in my last post to this thread it breaks the next page - this is the page that uploads it to the database, so no - it doesnt upload any data at all.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are trying to populate an `input type=time` with a value that isn't consistent with it. You can place the result into a regular `input type=text`, however if you are just trying to display the value, it's best not to place it into a form field in the first place because users can/will modify those values and then you have to add more markup to make the fields read only.

After separating your code into valid code that follows modern standards, and changing the container for the output from an `input type=time` to a `div`, it works. Below, I'm showing how to place the result in both a textbox as well as the preferred `div`.

```js
// Get DOM references:
var btn = document.getElementById("startTime_button");
var output1 = document.getElementById("output1");
var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");

// Set up click event handler:
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var result = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, { 
                                                        hour: '2-digit', 
                                                        minute:'2-digit', 
                                                        second:'2-digit'
                                                     });
                                                       
  output1.textContent = result;
  output2.value = result;
});
```

```html
<!-- timer is not a valid element -->
<div>
  <input id="startTime_button" name = "starttime_button" type="button" value="Start Timer">
  <div id="output1"></div> <!-- If you are just outputting a value, don't use a form element -->
  <input type="text" id="output2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will try this in about an hour - out of time now. I need to both output the time the button was pressed on the page when it is pressed, and also add that value to my database when the final commit button is pressed. If you need me to I can copy the 2 pages of the stuff  have in full, but am worried a little about the hosts space (could edit it down a bit tho)

Comment: @Brian, Then you could store the value in an `input type=hidden` so that it is transmitted when your form submits, but not shown to the user at all.

Comment: Thanks for that - still havent tried this, but the idea that a user can change this is good - the site is to add ticket data to a database. If the user is interupted during a call then they amend the start time to more closely record the total time taken to close the ticket. I have successfully got a bit of code to captur the time when the button is cliced to pass the data to the databse, but I cant get a form inside a form so this method wont work for the start time. As a beginner, this project could probably be written better to allow what I want better, but I am learning a lot :)

Comment: @ Scott Marcus - Had chance to try this now. I get no errors when running the code, but the text box isnt populated and the starttime doesnt show in the database. So perhaps Im 1/2 way there??? I will look a bit more at this code.

Comment: @Brian Well, as you can see from my sample code, the text box does populate (as long as the button's click event handler is triggered), so there's got to be something you are doing in your code that is not quite the same as what I've shown here.

Comment: Yep - I can see it works in the snippet, but it wont work when I copy and paste it into my code (I know its not the best way to learn, but if I can get it to work to start with, then I can take it apart later and see why it works).  I have the first box in php tags and the second box without them. Is this where I am going wrong?